# Is it possible to save multiple radgrids in batch edit mode?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I have 3 radgrids on a page that have the possibility of being in batch edit.

Would it be possible to have a button that saves all of the changes at once? The save button on each of the tables only saves that one table, and wipes all of the other changes.

Really the only thing I have so far are the three tables like so:

```
< telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid3" runat="server" AllowAutomaticDeletes="true" AllowAutomaticUpdates="true" OnItemDataBound="RadGrid1_ItemDataBound" OnItemDeleted="RadGrid3_ItemDeleted" MasterTableView-EditMode="Batch" MasterTableView-BatchEditingSettings-EditType="Cell" >
```

and of course the  for all of them with the appropriate select/insert/update/delete queries

Comment: how about showing some code and I would say yes..anything is possible if logically coded the right way ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the client-side API to save each grid.  See http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-batch-editing.html.

In JS, for some Save button, you can do something like

```
grid1.get_batchEditingManager().saveAllChanges();
```

for each grid.

Comment: I tried that just now, but the problem is that it only updates the last table.

Comment: Make sure your button doesn't trigger a postback which wipes out the other changes.  Try adding a UseSubmitBehavior="False" to your button.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working either. Whenever saveAllChanges or saveChanges is called, it forces the repost.

Comment: Well, i got it. I forgot to use the radajax manager, and have the button update the tables and the codeblock it's in. Thank you for your help.